# Jquery hide and show css class but only content inside current div, not any other

Tags: jquery, css, parent, slidetoggle

I have loop in wordpress that generates a div with two divs inside and a hide and a show element like below -

```
<div class="vacancy-desc">
 <div class="short-desc">
   Content
 </div>                 
 <div class="full-desc">
   Content               
 </div>       
 <a href="#" class="link show">MORE <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
 <a href="#" class="link hide"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span> LESS</a>
</div>
```

Because this is in the loop there may be several of these exact boxes on the same page.

I want to be able to click on the .show link to expand the .full-desc (which is hidden via css) and the .show to disappear, and the .hide to appear (which is also hidden by css). Then I want the opposite where I can click .hide it will toggle .full-desc shut, disappear and unhide .show.

I can get all this to happen but it targets every .hide .show on the page. What am I missing that allows me to create this script but only target the classes within its parent div?

```
<script>
$('.vacancy-desc a.show').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).prev().slideToggle('slow');
  $(this).hide();
});

$('.vacancy-desc a.hide').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).prev().slideToggle('slow');
  $(this).hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<script>
    $('.vacancy-desc a.show').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parents('.vacancy-desc').find('.full-desc').slideToggle('slow');
        $this.hide();
        $this.parents('.vacancy-desc').find('a.hide').show();
    });

    $('.vacancy-desc a.hide').click(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          var $this = $(this);
          $this.parents('.vacancy-desc').find('.full-desc').slideToggle('slow');
          $this.hide();
          $this.parents('.vacancy-desc').find('a.show').show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant. You forget to add the variable into the second part though :o) Thankyou, this makes perfect sense too, I'm slowly learning jquery and this is a nice clean example! Cheers

Comment: I was pleased you gave me the chance to work out what was wrong with it, and I did it!